# Does Google Shows the AJAX based website results in search?

Tags: ajax, database, search

I want to know that i am making a website which shows all the latest information on the front page... the website is completely AJAX working , So all the data is in the Server Databases , If someone searches for a perticular data available in my site through Search engines then will the search engine searches the database?

Comment: It's google headache,You need not to bother about it.Today many sites are working on ajax

Answer (score 1):

By default, no, AJAX-only accessible content is not going to be crawled by Google. There is a convention you can use, however, to ensure that it does get crawled - the "Hash Wallop".

When Google (and other search engines), encounter a link that starts with "#!", it will "crawl" the dynamic content returning from an AJAX call.  To take advantage of this, rather than having something like:

```
<a href="#">trigger ajax</a>
```

...you will want to use something like:

```
<a href="#!some-ajax-content">trigger ajax</a>
```

There is some more info on the technique here (and lots of others sites, just google it): http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-to-allow-google-to-crawl-ajax-content

Answer (score 0):

Some insight: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/27/searchable-dynamic-content-with-ajax-crawling/

Also, you might want to look into HTML caching, it will boost your SEO performance.